# SEO for Google Maps applications?

Tags: seo, google, search-results, google-maps

I have a webapp that is a customized Google Map; it's an interactive map of the Paris Metro.

In Google's SERP, the only thing that appears beneath the domain name is "Sorry, we have no imagery here", which is really not helpful. Here's how it looks like: [image: Sorry, we have no imagery here.]

I believe this text comes from Google Maps. I tried to set the

```
<meta name="description"
```

and

```
<noscript>
```

elements, to no avail. What else should I do? Ideally I'd like to have the text in the meta/description tag show up in search results; but having *nothing* would be better than "Sorry, we have no imagery here"...

The site itself is here: [vasyenmetro.com](http://vasyenmetro.com/?lang=en)

PS: it seems some of Google's own pages suffer from the same problem ([this one](http://www.google.com/intl/fr-CA/maps/about/) or [that one](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=MAP&q=select+col12%3E%3E0+from+1z1_-fPwad0Z7U8iotRE_fkN5bWWqQX_No8aPIos&h=false&lat=44.951300619514654&lng=-89.56949049999997&z=6&t=1&l=col12%3E%3E0&y=2&tmplt=2) for example, found [searching for 'Sorry we have no imagery here'](https://www.google.fr/search?q="sorry+we+have+no+imagery+here"))...

Comment: Yes, I am sure about one thing that its really coming from Google maps.

Comment: Might be because Google believes the page is too thin, also it doesn't help that your starting your current description with a separator which I'd imagine is invalid, see:. `<meta name="description" content=" - Interactive Paris Metro Map. Intuitive and cool!" />`

Comment: This wasn't the case until yesterday so I don't think it's the reason; however I just corrected it. We'll see.